# API's and services of a website

Tags: java, android, web

I am developing an app for a website at present, I have obtained the login API for it and successfully implemented this (the login). Now I want to move on further into the rest of the pages in the website. My doubt is, will there be a separate API for each of these pages? Should I use a different url address for each of these pages?

I don't know much about HTML or web development some clarity in this matter would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, this is a question you should ask to the web site owners, if they provide a separate or the same API. But in general, after succesfully logging in, you should get an authentication token that will use to make subsequent requests.

Comment: Ah, Ok. Thanks. I'll do that. Do you happen to have a good link where I can read about website services and API's in general? I would like to understand the process better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should ask the Webservice developer about its documentation. They should provide you with a well documentation for the Webservice.

Normally a documentation should describe the accessing methods, parameters, response,etc.

[W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/default.asp) Provides a good tutorial about webservices. This [link](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/default.asp) mighe help u.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your answer. I have already asked them. I will look at the tutorial also. :)